# view_as use in Boost Polygon library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-polygon

Can anyone guide me how `view_as` can be used. Or maybe an example in boost polygon library?

In documentation, it's mentioned that we can type cast from one to another.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_polygon_90_concept.htm

Comment: If the docs mention that, perhaps you can link to it so we know what you mean. It's not clear to me

Answer (score 1):

The boost::polygon documentation is not great, but in this area at least it does seem to be fairly clear:

> An object that is a model of `polygon_90_concept` can be viewed as a model of any of its refinements if it is determined at runtime to conform to the restriction of those concepts.  This concept casting is accomplished through the `view_as<>()` function.

```
view_as<rectangle_concept>(polygon_90_object)
```

> The return value of `view_as<>()` can be passed into any interface that expects an object of the conceptual type specified in its template parameter.